# Raspberry Pi intrerrupt handlers

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, interrupt

I'm trying to build a program (on Raspberry Pi) that reads sensor data. When the program spots a certain pattern in the sensor data I'd like a piece of code to be executed immediately. I don't want the OS to switch to any other task or handle anything else. Is there a way to force such a constraint from Python/Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer, please try to improve it. There's no indication of what the data is, or how it's being read or what other tasks you want to suppress or why.

Comment: Interrupt handers should avoid processing data.  A Linux device driver should not specify that *"a piece of code to be executed immediately"*.   Learn about the separation of kernel and userspace applications.  Microcontrollers and baremetal projects may have poorly constructed firmware that blur those distinctions, but if you intend to use Linux, then adapt to real OS requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try to be more specific .

The inputs from GPIO Zero have properties that allow you to use interrupts like when_pressed for buttons [readthedocs](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html#gpiozero.Button.when_pressed). these will call a function where you can test the pattern and run the code you want
you can also use polling and every time you read the sensor, you test the pattern and if match you execute the code you want.